# Magento2 how to stop generating Cache for Images?

Tags: cache, image

I don't want Magento to generate cache for images. How can I restrict cache generation for images?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable cache by going in Magento backend

Go to System -> Tools -> Cache Management Check image cache box select disable from action then save it this will disable image cache. Hope this might help.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Hi @Mayur, Thanks for your quick response. Actually we won't have any image cache box to disable it from cache management.

Comment: Which Magento version you are using?

Comment: "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": "2.2.0",